# iOS Images display abnormally in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, imageview

I'm trying to put some images into a UITableView, so I put an Image View into the UITableViewCell and set it aspect fit.

After starting the simulator, it appears to be right, but when I click at one cell or scroll out the originally hidden cells(may be the reused ones), the image breaks the limit of the image view's setting and destroys the layout.

[image: the middle picture is normal, but the upper or lower one is out of shape]

the middle picture is normal, but the upper or lower one is out of shape.

cellForRowAtIndexPath function as follow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShangbaoOriginCell";
    ShangbaoOriginCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.newsSampleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Cell %d",), indexPath.row];
    cell.cellView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    cell.imageView.image = self.tableItems[indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

whether cell.imageView.contentMode is set or not, this problem exists.

[image]

I've added bg color, ImageView is black, Content View is blue, Cell is green.

So I saw incredible thing, the (table view) cells become not wide enough (you can see from the narrow gap between two pictures). Which is set properly in story board that the cell's width cover the whole screen.

I forgot to say that this table view is in a tabbed application, but I think this doesn't matter . And this time I have added constraints to the image view, but in vain.

Comment: give autolayout constrains to your imageview

Comment: enter the cellForRowAtIndexPath code here.

Comment: @Suresh code uploaded.

Comment: @JayGajjar I'll have a try. thanks.

Comment: Use autolayout for the imageview to fit it in the left like Jay Said.  .What's the cellView here? Also to view the imageview's bounds, set its background color to red and see the output.

Comment: @Suresh OK, cellView is the UIView that the imageView belong to(just to test).

Comment: Then that should create the problem, just change the bg color for the view and image view and test. Also you can directly place the image view in the cell.Contentview

Comment: Sorry to bother again, @Suresh, but I've tried and failed. The details are added above. I can't understand why the cell width varies.